# Merging in tfs removing the package entry in .csproj from sharepoint project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tfs

I have a visual studio solution (2012) which contains couple of sharepoint projects. 
Each one have package entries in their csproj file. 
But when I am doing merging of these projects into other branch of tfs, then shocking the projects in merge branch don't have package entry in their csproj file due to which I am unable to publish the wsp. 
Please help me out in resolving this issue. Am I doing something wrong?